# Running Xdebug on netbeans but waiting for localhost to using WAMP but No respond on windows 8.1

Tags: xdebug, wampserver, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins, php-5.5

guys ,i had spent almost 12 hours and reviewed all answers  configuration of WAMP,Netbeans 8.0.2 ,PHP 5.5.12 and PHP extensions and XDEBUG 2.3.3 configuration on php.ini files and WAMP and PHP and the files in WWW file are running well. and my php.ini configuration are like below:

```
zend_extension = "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on 
xdebug.remote_handle=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_host=localhost 
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

and even for running phpinfo(); from PHP files in netbeans i get error like below:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT (03:38:32:924 | error, network)
  at https://anddogen.com/ad.php?u=08aa4bec8d2ecf3cbc43cd659ec5d353&c=gpupdater&p=1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT (03:38:33:753 | error, network)
  at https://anddogen.com/ad.php?u=08aa4bec8d2ecf3cbc43cd659ec5d353&c=gpupdater&p=1
Debugging session with browser was closed.
```

i had guess maybe the problem would be because of my pc network roots but because i m not good at network almost give up on this.could any one tell whats going on?
Thank you all.

Comment: find out the RIGHT ANSWER by: http://zurmo.org/forums/index.php?/topic/921-easy-debugging-with-netbeans-and-xdebug/                                           the problem was,after configuration of your local host ip address,u should uncheck ' stop at first line' which is default by netbeans 8.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT means that you are probably running some addon in your browser that is blocking this request. Try another browser or disable the addon.